# Replacement for $eval in VueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

`$eval` has been removed from Vue 2.

But, consider this JSFiddle (Vue 1): https://jsfiddle.net/kvdmolen/0w193c75

Here is JSFiddle with Vue 2.0.7: https://jsfiddle.net/kvdmolen/0w193c75/1/

Imagine this is actually a component (a table with configurable columns).

Any ideas how I should replace `$eval` for Vue 2?

Using `eval()` this doesn't work as it is outside of the `v-for` scope

Comment: Do you mean $eval in title as well?
And what is the issue in the fiddle, it seems working fine to me.

Comment: Ah mistake, thanks!

Comment: The jsfiddle is using VueJS 1, not VueJS 2!

Comment: No, Js fiddle is using [vue 2.0.5](https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js)

Comment: No, sorry, jsfiddle is messing up with the dropdown pre-selector. it was using Vue 1. Try this one: https://jsfiddle.net/kvdmolen/0w193c75/ and then switch in the javascript dropdown Vue version

Comment: Do you really really really need to eval?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using eval, You can write the code by calling a function from HTML, and in the field you can write a function, which will determine what will be the output.

in Html:

```
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in myitems">
            <td v-for="column in mycolumns" v-text="myFunc(index, column.field)"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
```

in Vue Component:

```
    mycolumns: [
            {
                column: "Todo Name",
            field: (item) =>  item.name
        },
            {
                column: "Status",
            field: (item) =>  item.status
        },
            {
                column: "Status Explanation",
            field: (item) =>  item.status == 1 ? 'Done' : 'Todo'
        }
    ]
},
methods:{
   myFunc(index, fn){
     return fn(this.myitems[index])
   }
}
```

check working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gnf33er/).

However this does not seem to be very good practice, as now your data is tightly bind to your html. So your container component and presentation container are not independent, can not grow independently and are error prone as well.

Comment: I think JSFiddle is not sweet with external resources. Consider this one: https://jsfiddle.net/kvdmolen/0w193c75/1/ it has the built-in external resource and it does not work with Vue 2 (but works with Vue 1 if you change back to $eval)